# Share imessage contact iphone

Tags: iphone, messages

When I receive a phone call from from unknown callers my iPhone occasionally displays caller ID information.  I assume iMessage is receiving it in the background.

How do I set this up for my iPhone for my number and contact?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, caller ID info is sent by the mobile carrier, isn't it?  Are you asking how you can add your info to display on other people's phones?

Comment: @fsb in this case I'm certain it isn't that imessage has a built in protocol for this

Comment: www.cnet.com/google-amp/news/imessage-vs-googles-new-texting-update-can-androids-messaging-app-take-on-apple/

Comment: Here is the answer https://www.addictivetips.com/ios/fix-sharing-name-and-photo-not-available-on-ios/amp/

Comment: If that's the answer to your question then you should add it as an Answer and accept it.